# What system call does Evince use to open pdf?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls, read, evince

I have tried to hook system calls using linux kernel module. However, when I open a pdf file using Evince, I find no `open`,`read` and `write` is used on this specific file, only `lstat` is used.

[Here](https://github.com/taoxinyi/taoxinyi.github.io/blob/master/evince.log) is the `strace` log of `strace evince folder1/test.pdf`

So I wonder what system call does evince use to `open` and`read` from file?

Comment: Try `strace` with the `-f` (follow) option, since the `clone` call creates a subprocess.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks, I've updated the log in the link. Now I can see `open("/home/xytao/folder1/test.pdf", O_RDONLY)` in line 5376, but I still don't see `read`, maybe because it's using `pread`?

Comment: perhaps the socket I/O is what's doing it - or `pread` can.  Reading the source-code would help :-)

Comment: Yes, pread. This is the start of the PDF file: `pread(19, "%PDF-1.3\r\n%\241\263\305\327\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<</Fil"..., 256, 0) = 256`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @ThomasDickey, you need to pass `strace` the `-f` option, in order to include the trace of all the threads.

(The `clone()` syscalls are creating new threads, not processes, but you still need `-f` to [have `strace` follow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7698209/9447571).)

Once you're following all threads, the `open` becomes aparent, opening the file in read-only mode, on file descriptor 19:

```
open("/home/xytao/folder1/test.pdf", O_RDONLY) = 19
```

The contents of the file are read using a succession of `pread` calls into a small 256 character buffer, the first of which gets the `%PDF-1.3` header:

```
pread(19, "%PDF-1.3\r\n%\241\263\305\327\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<</Fil"..., 256, 0) = 256
```

If you go through the trace, you'll see it will then `lseek` to the end of the file (to determine file size), then read a couple of blocks of data from there. I assume that's information about the pages in the document.

The following `pread`s happen at offsets in the middle of the file, but all of them seem to start with some information about "page", so I assume that's evince figuring out about the pages in the PDF document, probably using offsets it got from the end of the file.